# Using Image within Messi Dialog Box

Tags: jquery

I  want to insert an image inside the Messi Dialog Box. When i try to use , it throws error.

The below is the script..

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var html="<p><center> <img alt="Image" src="flower.jpg"> <br>Welcome</center></p>";
        $('.about').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            new Messi(html, {title: 'Messi Example',titleClass: 'info',modal:true,'center':'true',width:'400px',buttons: [{id: 0, label: 'Ok', val: 'Close'}],viewport:[{top: '30px', left: '30px'}]});
        });
    });
```

Click event is fired when link is clicked

Click Me

Every help is valuable..

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your html variable wrong.

```
var html="<p><center> <img alt="Image" src="flower.jpg"> <br>Welcome</center></p>";
```

Should be:

```
var html='<p><center> <img alt="Image" src="flower.jpg"> <br>Welcome</center></p>';
```

or:

```
var html="<p><center> <img alt=\"Image\" src=\"flower.jpg\"> <br>Welcome</center></p>";
```

Not sure what version of Messi you use, but there is a built-in fuction to load images in marcosesperon's version.

Use:

```
Messi.img('messi.jpg');
```